# Method name expected --> ; expected errors from my scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been learning Unity for the past week or so and getting help from friends, but I've run into a roadblock that me or my friends can't seem to get past

Currently the goal in mind is to have a prefab instantiate in sync with a songs BPM.

This is a class I had found from a redditor:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Conductor : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Conductor to Sync with music
    int crotchetsperbar = 8;
    public float bpm = 101;
    public float crotchet;
    public float songposition;
    public float deltasongpos;
    public float lasthit; //the last (snapped to beat) time key was pressed
    public float actuallasthit;
    float nextbeattime = 0.0f;
    float nextbartime = 0.0f;
    public float offset = 0.2f; //positive means song must be minussed
    public float addoffset; //additional, per level offset
    public static float offsetstatic = 0.40f;
    public static bool hasoffsetadjusted = false;
    public int beatnumber = 0;
    public int barnumber = 0;
}
```

And here's the script I'm using to instantiate my prefab:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BPMinstantiator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bpmOB;
    public GameObject bpmClone;

    public Conductor script;

    float lastbeat; //this is the 'moving reference point'
    float bpm = 140;
    float dsptimesong;

    void Start()
    {
        Conductor script = bpmOB.GetComponent<Conductor>();
        lastbeat = 0;
        script.crotchet = 60 / bpm;
        dsptimesong = (0)AudioSettings.dspTime;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        script.songposition = (0)(AudioSettings.dspTime - dsptimesong) *song.pitch - offset;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("update start");
        if (script.songposition > lastbeat + script.crotchet)
        {
            Debug.Log("If statement worked");
            bpmClone = Instantiate(bpmOB, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("clone is assigned");
            lastbeat += script.crotchet;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the errors I've been getting are these:

**Assets\Scripts\BPMinstantiator.cs(23,31): error CS0149: Method name expected**
`*Appears when dsptimesong = (0)AudioSetting.dspTime; is not present*`

**Assets\Scripts\BPMinstantiator.cs(21,26): error CS1002: ; expected**
`*Appears when the former line of code is present*`

The second error in particular always has (21,26) regardless of how I edit the code

I've looked all over the internet and I can't seem to find anything that really works so I'd really love some help or an answer!!!

Comment: In start you are redefining script. So after the start is over it will be null

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `(0)AudioSettings.dspTime` and `(0)(AudioSettings.dspTime - dsptimesong) *song.pitch - offset` is valid code. The syntax indicates that you want to cast/convert to a type like...

```
float myFloatValue = 5f;
int num = (int)myFloatValue;
```

To summarize: Remove the `(0)` or replace it with `(float)` if a type cast to float is needed, and you should be fine:

```
void Start()
{
    Conductor script = bpmOB.GetComponent<Conductor>();
    lastbeat = 0;
    script.crotchet = 60 / bpm;
    dsptimesong = AudioSettings.dspTime;
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    script.songposition = (AudioSettings.dspTime - dsptimesong) *song.pitch - offset;
}
```

Comment: from the examples and tutorials I looked at, the (0) was (float) but I wasn't entirely clear on what I was supposed to put there. I remember it being for marking where the audio begins? Sorry, I'm really new to Unity and C# as a whole so this stuff really boggles my mind.

Comment: No need to apologize, sorry if I sounded angry or judging. We're all at different stages of learning! And I'm here because I like helping people learn!

Comment: So basically if you put `(float)` in front you will CAST (convert) the value type from whatever it is, to a float. You cannot convert anything, only things that are kinda similar. You could convert an INT to a FLOAT because an int 0 makes sense to a float because they share fundamentally being numbers. But a string "hello" cannot be converted to float because they dont share the fundamentals of being numeric values.

Comment: I cannot see if the casting `(float)` is needed or not, because I do not know what TYPE `AudioSettings.dspTime` is, but it will not be harmful to put `(float)` there.

Comment: btw sounds like you're making a very cool game! Love the concept!

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you so much for the help! And thank you, I hope this game comes out well!